# Split string? vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Can someone please point me in the right direction. I have a simple vb.net application that converts PDF to txt and reads line by line to create a csv file. The original Pdf has changed and I need to modify my code. For example from the line below how could I extract or split each category? For example just the `xxxxxxxx` for tech ID, `DOE JOHN` and `xxxxxxxx` from account number?

```
line =  "Tech ID: xxxxxxxxxx Name: DOE, JOHN Account #: xxxxxxxx"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `Split` method:

```
Dim line As String = "Tech ID: xxxxxxxxxx Name: DOE, JOHN Account #: xxxxxxxx"
Dim separators() As String = {"Tech ID:", "Name:", "Account #:"}
Dim result() As String
result = line.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: @fpena06: You should accept the answer, then - click the green checkbox to its left.